# can zend_form be used with pagination?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-paginator

I am not sure if this is the most sensible way of doing this but I thought I would ask anyway.

I have a 'wizard' that I am developing for users to review data that is stored in the database. Each part of the wizard is a simple Zend_Form allowing the users to review and edit the data.  However one element of the wizard needs to be a bit more dynamic.

The dynamic bit needs to be able to allow the users to 'scroll' through multiple instances of the same for with different data in it, as you would scroll through the records of a database. However with the user being able to update the data displayed.  They must also be able to add and remove TextBox elements to the form (I was planning on adding these elements with javascript/dojo) but each TextBox element needs to be saved before moving on to the next form.

I am thinking of using Zend_paginator to accomplish this but as each click though is a _GET request, is it possible to make it _POST so that I can handle the form request before moving the user to the next record?

I hope this makes sense, it is quite difficult to describe, however if there is a better way of achieving this functionality I would be interested in hearing how, (esp if it makes my life a little easier)

Thanks...

Comment: Can you explain a little further what you are trying to accomplish? Can you provide a sample page in the form so that we can see what they might be paginating through? Without a bit more information on the specific use case, its impossible to say whether this is really the best solution.

Comment: I would say the best example I can think of is something like an access form where you can scroll through the records but the form layout stays the same.  Each click on the 'next' record commits the data to the db and moves to the next record.

Answer (score 1):

I've read that multi-page forms will be officially supported by Zend Framework in the future, but for now your best solution is an implementation like the [one detailed in the reference guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html#zend.form.advanced.multiPage).